# How to pass data to vue

Tags: laravel, vue.js

In ExampleComponent I listen to event and I receive user's IP. Then I would like to display data in a vue. But how can I pass this data(variable $ip)? I mean instead of just console.log it, I should bring data to my page(console.log works).

```
<script>
export default {
    data: function() {
        return {
   ip:''
},
     mounted() {
        window.Echo.channel('channelName')
            .listen('eventIp', (e) => {
              this.ip=e
            })
        }
     }
</script>
```

As for ExampleComponent it's built to my admin page where I listen for events.

It is just a line <
example-component>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add data section in your script like  this:

```
<script>
export default {
data(){
   return{
     ip:''
   }
},
```

before script and inside template tag add a div,p,h1,span, etc. to show ip variable.

```
<template>
.
.
.
<div v-html="ip"></div>
.
.
.
</template>
```

then change ip variable when you receive channel info:

```
    mounted() {
        window.Echo.channel('channelName')
            .listen('eventIp', (e) => {
                this.ip=e
            })
   }
}
```

automatically the value of  change to ip value.

Comment: Where should I put the first script?I've already exported the mounted() { ... in my ExampleComponent.

Comment: before mounted. just add data()... ,

Comment: [Vue warn]: Property or method "ip" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render.

Comment: @ Hamid Shariati I did  what you have proposed. But this produced a compile error and an ExampleComponent didn't mount.

Comment: I updated a question with more information. Check it out.

Comment: I'm sure you have a syntax error or a mistake in sort of codes. can you share this part of your code in github gist?

Comment: You were right. I forgot to put some parenthesis. By the way , is there a way  not to override every time this data? I would like to display all users as they subscribe.

Comment: this is out of this question . ask a new and add your back end where your override. by default every user have an ip and his/her ip will view ...

Comment: Please take a look at another question I opened https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58058580/how-to-get-data-by-axios-call-in-a-mounted-component/58059225#58059225