# How to get data by axios call in a mounted component?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, axios

I'm working on getting data from API by performing api call with axios. But my attempts to get data from api aren't succesful. How to make it work?

```
export default { 
    mounted() {
         this.fetchData()
    },
    data() {
       return {
         users:[]
    }    
  },

  methods: {
     fetchData(){
        axios.get('api/person')
              .then(response => (this.users= response.data))
              .catch(error => console.log(error));
      }
   }, 
}
```

In ExampleComponent have these lines

```
<template>
 ...
 <div>{{users.name}}</div>
 <div>{{users.ip}}</div>
 ...
</template>
```

In api.php

```
Route::get('/person', function() {
    $users = DB::table('user_info')->select('ip','name')->get();
     return $users;
 });
```

Running php artisan tinker I did

```
 DB::table('user_info')->select('ip','name')->get();
```

I've got all my data from DB(users with names and IP's).
 In the dev console, I see my data in response tab. But it is nothing in my page.

Comment: any error you facing?

Comment: show the error logs

Comment: @tinwan I have no errors and no data.

Comment: @Karan Sadana No visible errors detected.

Comment: had your php backend gotten the request infomation after you refresh your page?

Comment: @tinwan  This is how it all organized. User logged in, I get his credentials and show it on my admin page. So in my mounted component, I also listen for event(I didn't publish this snippet). GET and POST calls work well in Postman. But for now, I just want to display already present data on my admin page.

Comment: are the page address‘s host  and the backend url's host same ?

Comment: @tinwan Could you be more specifiс? I am not sure I've got it right.

Comment: check your network tab by doing inspect, what you get in return from api

Comment: try DB::table('user_info')->select('ip','name')->get(); in php artisan tinker. what's the result. add int to your question as updated.

Comment: @Hamid Shariati  Running this command, I've got all my data from DB(users with names and IP's).

Comment: @Hamid Shariati I looked in the dev console and saw my data in response tab. But it is nothing  in my page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need v-for:

```
<div v-for="user in users">
 <div>{{user.name}}</div>
 <div>{{user.ip}}</div>
</div>
```

so for every users you will show info.

Comment: you're welcome. nice to meet you. thanks for solve checked.

Comment: I have another question. It's all about the same code, but small problems which I encounter. Please, check it out If you like to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58063168/how-to-update-vue-component-after-it-receives-data

Answer (score 1):

There is a problem in vue : it should be {users.ip} and {users.name} in template.

Comment: I added these lines but still no data fetched.

Answer (score 1):

that is how i get my data.

```
<script>
  export default {
   data() {
     return {
       properties: []
      }
   },
   methods: {
     loadproperty(){
       axios.get('allhouses').then(response => this.properties = response.data);
      },
   },
   mounted() {
    this.loadproperty();
    }
   }

</script>
```