# How to update Vue component after it receives data

Tags: vue.js

When a component is mounted, I get data on my page. Then, I would like to see my component updates every time the user logged in(for this purpose I listen for this event). For now, I get data from DB and in the div "ip" I got logged in user. But I intend to  dynamically add this new data to my already received data. How can I update data dynamically?  I would like to get the page with a newly inserted user without refreshing the page. This logged in user appears here  and gets added to  only if I refresh the page. I want to get it without the need of refreshing the page. It's about rerendering component with new props.

In template

```html
<div v-for="user in users">
    <div class="card-header">{{ user.ip }}</div>
    <div class="card-header">{{ user.name }}</div>
</div>
<div v-html="ip"></div>
```

In script

```
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            users: [],
            ip: ''
        }
    },
    mounted() {
        window.Echo.channel('channelName')
            .listen('eventIp', (e) => {
                this.ip = e
            }),
            this.fetchData()
    },
    methods: {
        fetchData() {
            axios
                .get('api/person')
                .then(response => (this.users = response.data))
                .catch(error => console.log(error));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `console.log(e);` before `this.ip=e`, what's the output?

Comment: @Caddy DZ It displays my posted data as an object('name' and 'ip').

Comment: Then use that `e` to update your data instead of using Ajax, the purpose of Echo is to broadcast new data when it changes dynamically

Answer (score 0):

if eventIp is just one ip:

```
<div v-for="user in users">
    <div class="card-header">{{ user.ip }}</div>
    <div class="card-header">{{ user.name }}</div>
    <div v-if="ip==user.ip">online</div>
</div>
```

if eventIp includes multi online ip:

```
<div v-for="user in users">
    <div class="card-header">{{ user.ip }}</div>
    <div class="card-header">{{ user.name }}</div>
    <div v-for"userIp in ip">
      <span v-if="userIp==user.ip">online</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

updated:
as you explain in comments you need to listen channel. this link  https://pusher.com/tutorials/todo-vue-laravel#building-vue-components is good section of a tutorial for this.

when new user created you need more data of new  user in channel and add it to users variable. automatically vue render it in html.

Comment: I would like to get the page with a newly inserted user without refreshing the page. This logged in user appears here <div v-html="ip"></div> and gets added to <div v-for="user in users"> only if I refresh the page. I want to get it without the need of refreshing the page. I know the React has some method to deal with this. It's about rerendering component with new props.